# Bash : how to allow arrow keys in readarray

Tags: bash

I'm trying to allow arrow keys in bash user input `readarray`. I know that you can allow them in `read` using `-e` but do you have any ideas for `readarray` ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readarray` isn't intended for interactive use, so it does not support using the Readline library for editing its input. Instead, you just need to use `read` in a loop.

```
declare -a arr
while read -re; do
    arr+=( "$REPLY" )
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And just for information for others people, if you want to use `TAB` but not for completion use `CTRL-V` then `TAB`.